# Can I manage lifecycle owner, injecting viewModel with Koin?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, lifecycle, koin

I have single Activity application.

I want to bind viewModel to the parent fragment lifecycle (`FlowFragmentLogin`), and share it with child fragments (`CellFragment`, `InfoFragment`, `etc`). So that when I move from `FlowFragmentLogin` to `FlowFragmentMain`, viewModel `onCleared()` was called.

But the only way I found is to share viewModel between Activity, and its Fragments:
https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/documentation/koin-android/index.html

And no control over lifecycle-owners. Which is unacceptable for me, at least because this viewModel will live until the application's death.

Comment: Apparently you can specify the ViewModelStore, or at least that's what I've heard.

Comment: How about initiating one ViewModel at Activity, and fragments also have their own ViewModels, we can make ViewModels talk to each other. What do you say?

Answer (score 4):

Since Navigation `2.1.0-alpha02`:

> You can now create ViewModels that are scoped at a navigation graph level via the by navGraphViewModels() property delegate for Kotlin users or by using the getViewModelStore() API added to NavController.

You can find the change log [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha02) and the [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel).

Unfortunately Koin can not support the feature since `viewModel()` or `sharedViewModel()` was bond to Activity. But support for nav has already planned in `2.1.x` and you can track [here](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/442).

---

For now here's my solution:

1. Use `navGraphViewModels()` instead of `viewModel()` in Koin.

```
class DetailFr : Fragment() {
    private val vm: DetailViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.main_nav_graph)
}
```

2. Make ViwModel implements `KoinComponent` so that we can use `by inject()` instead of inject by constructor.

```
class DetailViewModel : ViewModel(), KoinComponent {

    private val repo: DetailRepository by inject()
    // othetr objects you need
}
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using new version of **Koin(2.1.0)** and some magic :)

All you need is add this extension function:

```
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.sharedGraphViewModel(
    @IdRes navGraphId: Int,
    qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
    noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
) = lazy {
    val store = findNavController().getViewModelStoreOwner(navGraphId).viewModelStore
    getKoin().getViewModel(ViewModelParameter(VM::class, qualifier, parameters, null, store, null))
}
```

And now you can simple get your ViewModel from nested graph by:

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModel by sharedGraphViewModel(R.id.my_graph)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Koin version `3.1.3` there is a new extension function `koinNavGraphViewModel`.

just add the following dependency

`implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-navigation:$koin_version"`

It can be used like this

`private val viewModel: MyViewModel by koinNavGraphViewModel(R.id.my_graph)`